# minimize browser window of plugin using c++

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, plugins

I have a plugin which is primarily used for screen-capture. It loads with the browser. Now on click of the button a small window appears notifying the screen capture has started.

Here, I also want the browser to get minimized.

I tried the following approaches:

**Approach 1.**

`HWND parentWH = ::FindWindow(L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1", L"test - SC1 - Google Chrome");`

```
::ShowWindow(parentWH,SW_MINIMIZE);
```

It works! But the question is that how should I take the parameters of FindWindow dynamically.
like, parameter1 being 'WindowClassName' and 2 being 'WindowTitle'. for **different browsers**.

**Approach 2.**

```
HWND parentWH = ::GetAncestor(this->pluginWindowHandle,GA_ROOTOWNER);
::ShowWindow(parentWH,SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Does Not Work!

Comment: To see if Approach 2 will work, start Spy++ that comes with Visual Studio and see if `this->pluginWindowHandle` has as an ancestor of the `Chrome_WidgetWin_1` window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me for minimizing the browser window.

Approach 1:

```
::ShowWindow(pluginWindowHandle,SW_HIDE);
parentWH = ::GetForegroundWindow(); //for obtaining parent window handle
::ShowWindow(parentWH,SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Approach 2:
 Before showing the plugin window, i'm getting the browser window handle

```
void NotificationWindow::showNotification()
{
    parentWH = ::GetForegroundWindow();
    ::ShowWindow(parentWH,SW_MINIMIZE);
    this->close();
    this->displayWindow();
}
```

Here, till the displayWindow() function is not called, we can get the browser window handle directly by using GetForegroundWindow() function.

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the browser window containing the plugin you've used to start a screen capture, I'd suggest the following steps:

1. Pass the document.title (JavaScript) of the page which embeds your plugin to the plugin.
2. Create an [EnumWindowsProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback function in your WinApi dll. This function will be given a HWND every time it is called. Inside this function you should use the [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to check if the document.title from the browser is a substring of the title corresponding to the current HWND. If it is, then you can minimize the current HWND using [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and if you want to restore it after a capture, you can store the HWND and use it again later. Return FALSE if you have found a match, and TRUE otherwise.
3. Use the [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to enumerate through the windows on your system. Into this, you will pass a pointer to the callback function above. EnumWindows will run until the callback function returns FALSE, or it has enumerated through all of the windows.